# error on calling Alfresco Rest API queries

Tags: solr, alfresco

I have installed Alfresco community version 6.2 (plus Share, Solr) and I am playing with its Rest API. But when I call the endpoint `"http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/queries/nodes?term=dog&orderBy=name"` I get the following error :

response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errorKey": "framework.exception.ApiDefault",
        "statusCode": 500,
        "briefSummary": "02150148 Request failed 500 /solr/alfresco/afts?wt=json&fl=DBID%2Cscore&rows=100&df=keywords&start=0&locale=en_US&alternativeDic=DEFAULT_DICTIONARY&sort=%40%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.alfresco.org%2Fmodel%2Fcontent%2F1.0%7Dname+asc&fq=%7B%21afts%7DAUTHORITY_FILTER_FROM_JSON&fq=%7B%21afts%7DTENANT_FILTER_FROM_JSON",
        "stackTrace": "For security reasons the stack trace is no longer displayed, but the property is kept for previous versions",
        "descriptionURL": "https://api-explorer.alfresco.com",
        "logId": "97b9c9e2-16cd-4a41-b68a-eb281448f0e8"
    }
}
```

solr.log (I dont know why there is no log in this file, maybe this is not the right Solr log file?!):

```
2020-03-15 08:28:47.558 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.Server jetty-9.3.14.v20161028
2020-03-15 08:28:48.800 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter  ___      _       Welcome to Apache Solr™ version 6.6.5-patched a77dde61f5121c726afb0e50a8e34ebba88534a4 - build - 2018-10-26 16:24:31
2020-03-15 08:28:48.801 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter / __| ___| |_ _   Starting in standalone mode on port 8983
2020-03-15 08:28:48.801 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter \__ \/ _ \ | '_|  Install dir: D:\alfresco-home\alfresco-search-services\solr
2020-03-15 08:28:48.821 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter |___/\___/_|_|    Start time: 2020-03-15T08:28:48.805381700Z
```

Alfresco log:

```
2020-03-15 17:36:08,673 ERROR [org.alfresco.rest.framework.webscripts.ResourceWebScriptGet] [http-nio-8080-exec-19] 73daefdf-a36e-4f88-b8d1-8d87c8c9dc6b : [org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.AbstractSolrQueryHTTPClient.postQuery(AbstractSolrQueryHTTPClient.java:108), org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.postSolrQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:1115), org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:582), org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryLanguage.executeQuery(SolrQueryLanguage.java:52), org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.DbOrIndexSwitchingQueryLanguage.executeQuery(DbOrIndexSwitchingQueryLanguage.java:217), org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrSearchService.query(SolrSearchService.java:354), org.alfresco.repo.search.SearcherComponent.query(SearcherComponent.java:84), jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor492.invoke(Unknown Source), java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43), java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566), org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:79), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186), org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212), com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.query(Unknown Source), org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.SearchServiceSubSystemDelegator.query(SearchServiceSubSystemDelegator.java:133), jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor492.invoke(Unknown Source), java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43), java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566), org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163), net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:80), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186), org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:53), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186), org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:166), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186), org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295), org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186), org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212), com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.query(Unknown Source), org.alfresco.rest.api.impl.QueriesImpl$AbstractQuery.find(QueriesImpl.java:421), org.alfresco.rest.api.impl.QueriesImpl.findNodes(QueriesImpl.java:285), java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method), java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62), java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43), java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566), org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163), org.alfresco.rest.api.impl.ExceptionInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionInterceptor.java:57), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186), org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212), com.sun.proxy.$Proxy196.findNodes(Unknown Source), org.alfresco.rest.api.queries.QueriesEntityResource.readById(QueriesEntityResource.java:74), org.alfresco.rest.api.queries.QueriesEntityResource.readById(QueriesEntityResource.java:44), org.alfresco.rest.framework.webscripts.ResourceWebScriptGet.executeAction(ResourceWebScriptGet.java:187), org.alfresco.rest.framework.webscripts.AbstractResourceWebScript$3.execute(AbstractResourceWebScript.java:206), org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:450), org.alfresco.rest.framework.webscripts.AbstractResourceWebScript.execute(AbstractResourceWebScript.java:199), org.alfresco.rest.framework.webscripts.AbstractResourceWebScript$1.execute(AbstractResourceWebScript.java:111), org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:450), org.alfresco.rest.framework.webscripts.AbstractResourceWebScript.execute(AbstractResourceWebScript.java:128), org.alfresco.rest.framework.webscripts.ApiWebScript.execute(ApiWebScript.java:115), org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:474), org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:664), org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScriptInternal(RepositoryContainer.java:435), org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:315), org.alfresco.rest.api.PublicApiRepositoryContainer.access$001(PublicApiRepositoryContainer.java:47), org.alfresco.rest.api.PublicApiRepositoryContainer$1.doWork(PublicApiRepositoryContainer.java:84), org.alfresco.repo.tenant.TenantUtil.runAsWork(TenantUtil.java:126), org.alfresco.repo.tenant.TenantUtil.runAsTenant(TenantUtil.java:95), org.alfresco.rest.api.PublicApiRepositoryContainer.executeScript(PublicApiRepositoryContainer.java:80), org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:399), org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:210), org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.TenantWebScriptServlet.service(TenantWebScriptServlet.java:82), javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166), org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166), org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.NullFilter.doFilter(NullFilter.java:75), jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor499.invoke(Unknown Source), java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43), java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566), org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:132), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186), org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212), com.sun.proxy.$Proxy255.doFilter(Unknown Source), org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:89), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166), org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:68), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166), org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.ClearSecurityContextFilter.doFilter(ClearSecurityContextFilter.java:53), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166), org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202), org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96), org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541), org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139), org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92), org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688), org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74), org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343), org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367), org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65), org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868), org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639), org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49), java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128), java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628), org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61), java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)]
```

Solr is working fine (I mean when I start Solr server I clearly see that I am able to search inside Share, and when I stop Solr I can not search anymore).

from the logs it seems that the problem is in `org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.AbstractSolrQueryHTTPClient.postQuery(AbstractSolrQueryHTTPClient.java:108)`.

I have no idea what is the problem, i will appreciate your help :)

**additional information :**

- I have not enabled ssl for alfresco and Solr yet.
- some other Rest API endpoints that I have tested works perfectly (not all, for example `GET tags` is also not working and showing same error as `GET queries/nodes`)

**update**(solr logs from its Web UI):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value already present: _dummy_
    at com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap.put(HashBiMap.java:241)
    at com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap.put(HashBiMap.java:218)
    at org.alfresco.solr.component.RewriteFacetParametersComponent.rewriteFacetFieldList(RewriteFacetParametersComponent.java:509)
    at org.alfresco.solr.component.RewriteFacetParametersComponent.fixFacetParams(RewriteFacetParametersComponent.java:198)
    at org.alfresco.solr.component.RewriteFacetParametersComponent.prepare(RewriteFacetParametersComponent.java:64)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.AlfrescoSearchHandler.handleRequestBody(AlfrescoSearchHandler.java:323)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2477)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:723)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:529)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:361)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)




---------------------------------------

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.alfresco.solr.query.Solr4QueryParser.getContentStore(Solr4QueryParser.java:195)
    at org.alfresco.solr.query.Solr4QueryParser.<init>(Solr4QueryParser.java:168)
    at org.alfresco.solr.AlfrescoSolrDataModel.getLuceneQueryParser(AlfrescoSolrDataModel.java:1414)
    at org.alfresco.solr.query.AlfrescoLuceneQParserPlugin$AlfrescoLuceneQParser.parse(AlfrescoLuceneQParserPlugin.java:85)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:168)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:161)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.AlfrescoSearchHandler.handleRequestBody(AlfrescoSearchHandler.java:323)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2477)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:723)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:529)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:361)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

**I see a lot of these two errors.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bootstrapped a fresh project using version 4.1.0 of the Alfresco SDK and brought it up. Hitting the same API endpoint that you are hitting does not return this error.

The response you are seeing, as well as the fact that your tags API is not working, tells me this is probably a SOLR problem.

Try going to your SOLR admin page. For example, when running using the SDK, the URL is:
http://localhost:8983/solr

You might see what the errors are immediately on the SOLR admin page, or you might have to go to "Logging".

Comment: I added SOLR logs, can you figure out what is the problem? thank you